# execute command on remote machine in bash script using password authentication

Tags: bash, ssh, sshpass

I have a bash script and I'm executing it on an ubuntu:20.04 this bash script requires a command to be executed on a remote Ubunut:20.04 server. The credentials for the remote machine are already set as env variables.

```
SSH_HOST=host_ip
SSH_USER=username
SSH_PASSWORD=password
```

This is the command in the bash script that executes the command on the remote machine.

```
sshpass -p $SSH_PASSWORD | ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SSH_USER@$SSH_HOST sudo /root/updates-watcher/update.sh
```

I keep getting the prompt for password even though I'm using sshpass in the script. I tried all the options available with sshpass ie:
-e env variable
-p directly putting the password in the command
-f putting the password in a file

But I got a password prompt with all attempts.

**Don't delete my question because there are already so many similar questions and trust me I've read all of them and answers on them don't work.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```
sshpass -p $SSH_PASSWORD  ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SSH_USER@$SSH_HOST sudo /root/updates-watcher/update.sh
```